# Formatting xaxis in graphs with secondary yaxis using plotly

Tags: r, plotly, format, x-axis

I am seeking assistance in changing the color of the x-axis to white in a Plotly graph that includes two y-axes. In the provided code below, my attempt to conceal the x-axis by setting it to white is not successful. I would appreciate any suggestions on how to achieve this. Thank you!

```
df <- tibble(x = 1:10, y1= seq(2, 6.5, .5), y2 = seq(4, -5, -1))
fig <- plotly::plot_ly()
fig <- fig %>%
  plotly::add_trace(data = df,
                    x = ~x, 
                    y = ~y1, 
                    type = 'scatter',
                    mode = 'lines',
                    linetype = "solid",
                    name = "y1 axis"
  )
fig <- fig %>%
  plotly::add_trace(data = df,
                    x = ~x, 
                    y = ~y2, 
                    type = 'scatter',
                    mode = 'lines',
                    linetype = "solid",
                    yaxis = "y2",
                    name = "y2 axis"
  )
x <- list(
  title = '',
  zerolinecolor = "#FFFFFF",
  zerolinewidth = 2,
  gridcolor = "#FFFFFF")
y <- list(
  title = '',
  zerolinecolor = '#ffff',
  zerolinewidth = 2,
  gridcolor = "#FFFFFF")
y2 <- list(
  overlaying = "y",
  side = "right")
fig <- fig %>%
  layout(xaxis = x,
         yaxis = y,
         yaxis2 = y2)
fig
```

I was expecting to format the color of the x-axis when there are two y-axis.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```r
x <- list(
  title = '',
  showline = TRUE,
  showgrid = FALSE,
  zeroline = FALSE)

y1 <- list(
  title = '',
  showline = TRUE,
  showgrid = FALSE,
  zeroline = FALSE)

y2 <- list(
  overlaying = "y",
  side = "right",
  showline = TRUE,
  showgrid = FALSE,
  zeroline = FALSE)

fig <- fig %>%
  layout(yaxis = y1,
         yaxis2 = y2,
         xaxis = x)
fig
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-12-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>